# How to display the time whenever value of the current minute changes (with Cocoa)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nstimer

Ok this one really has me stumped. The challenge *seems* simple but has a few restrictions that are really throwing me off.

Gist of the program:

(1) When the minute changes the application should output the current time with the format HH:mm:ss.

(2) When the second changes the application should output a character for every second and a different character for every tenth second (i.e. ".........|.........|"). Here it is important to note that I cannot just count seconds; rather, the program must know the value of the second of the current time and output the corresponding character only if it is divisible by 10.

Restrictions:

(1) The program can have 2 classes -- one for the minute display and one for the second display.

(2) Each class can contain only one void method that takes a timer as a parameter.

(3) The main function will create an object of each class and 2 NSTimers. **The first timer must have its interval set at 0.5 and must target the minutes object. The second timer must have its interval set at 0.1 and must target the seconds object.**

I would love to just set the first time to fire every minute and the second timer to fire ever second, but I am not allowed to tamper with that. This is as far as I got before I was stumped:

**main.m**:

```
MinuteDisplay *minutes = [[MinuteDisplay alloc] init];

__unused NSTimer *minutesTimer = 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
    target:minutes
    selector:@selector(minuteChange:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

**MinuteDisplay.m**:

```
- (void)minuteChange:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDateFormatter *testFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [testFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *nowString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSString *testString = [testFormatter stringFromDate:now];

    if ([testString isEqual:@"00"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", nowString];
    }
}
```

**Example output:**

```
01:09:00
//.5 second interval
01:09:00
```

I haven't even bothered with the second half of this challenge yet because I got stumped here. This *technically* works, but I know I'm doing it wrong, since the output isn't dependent upon the program knowing the *value of the minute has changed*. Also, because the timer is set to fire every .5 seconds, I get two lines of output every minute instead of just one (which does not satisfy the specs).

Can anyone suggest where to go from here? This one really has my mind boggled.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not modify the timer interval, the other alternative is to use an instance variable in your MinuteDisplay class, for example, `displayString`. And modify the `minuteChange` method as follows:

```
- (void)minuteChange:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDateFormatter *testFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [testFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *nowString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSString *testString = [testFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    if ([testString isEqual:@"00"]) {
                if(![nowString isEqualToString:dispString]) {
            dispString = nowString;
            NSLog(@"*************** %@", dispString);
        }
    }
}
```

This will make sure that it is logged only once a minute

Answer (score 0):

Working minuteChange method:

```
- (void)minuteChange:(NSTimer *)timer
{
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
if (!self.lastTime) {
    self.lastTime = [NSDate date];
}

if (now > self.lastTime) {
    if ([[self.seconds stringFromDate:now] isEqualToString:@"00"]) {
        printf("\n%s", [[self.output stringFromDate:now] UTF8String]);
        self.lastTime = now;
    }

}

self.output = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.output setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

self.seconds = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.seconds setDateFormat:@"ss"];

}
```

Working secondChange method:

```
- (void)secondChange:(NSTimer *)timer
{
long secondsSince1970 = time(NULL);

if (!self.lastSecond) {
    self.lastSecond = secondsSince1970;
}

if (secondsSince1970 > self.lastSecond) {
    if (secondsSince1970 % 10 == 0) {
        printf("|");
        self.lastSecond = secondsSince1970;
    } else {
        printf(".");
        self.lastSecond = secondsSince1970;
    }
}

}
```

**Changes to minuteChange:**
The most important change was the addition of the lastTime ivar to the class. Now it's simple...if lastTime is null, assign it the value of the current date. If current time is greater than last time, test if it's a new minute and then output the time if it is. ONLY update lastTime if a new minute was output (this ensures that the time is only displayed once per minute).

**secondChange:**
Took a different approach with this one and now I'm wishing I had gone with straight C the first time around. This one is so simple! Check if the current second is greater than the last second. If so, check if it's divisible by 10. If so, print "|". If not, print ".". Super easy and actually more accurate than setting the timer to fire every second. Sheesh.